# How to create a process stack?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have three projects in C# VS 2008 as follows:

1. Project 1: `Class1.function1()`
2. Project 2: `Class2.function1()`
3. Project 3: Calls `Class1.function1()` or `Class2.function1()` (they are not static)

The third project calls functions in distinct order. I want to "place" `function1()` and `function2()` in a list like this:

```
foreach(var function in functions)
{
    // calls function
    function();
}
```

but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something along these lines... since they aren't static you need to instantiate `Class1` and `Class2` objects and call the methods on those objects. Use an List of [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) delegates to iterate through the methods.

```
 var c1 = new class1();
 var c2 = new class2();
 var functions = new List<Action>(){ c1.function1, c2.function1 };
 foreach (var functionToCall in functions)
     functionToCall();
```